# how to get full text from specific user by tweepy

Tags: python, tweepy

I wonder how to get full text from specific user by tweepy...I have used  Twitter's tweet_mode=extended option like other stack posts said, but still..

I've seen a lot of people said using tweet_mode="extended" and request for tweet.full_text, so in the upper codes, that's how I did but still have only part of it.

nothing
pass...
fixed

Comment: Please include enough detail so that someone can reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.